# Add video path to file provider paths

Tags: android, android-camera, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider, android-video-record

How can I add video captured path in File Provider? I am getting `Content Uri` form `FileProvider`. The video I caputure using default Camera App returns `File Uri` on `Android 6.0`, for which content resolver returns null. I want to read video size from the content resolver `cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)`. How can I handle this issue?

Comment: Use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to steer the app to where you want the video to be stored. Have that location be one that is served by your `FileProvider`. Beyond that, what does "content resolver does not video size" mean?

Comment: It doesn't work too. I pass this File Uri to `Content Resolver` for fetching video size.

Comment: What does "fetching video size" mean? You might consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`, call `new File(uri.getPath()).length()` to get the length of the file. This should work if you have read access to the file.

Comment: And how can I open file input stream to this video? I also need name of this video?

Comment: @mallaudin: "And how can I open file input stream to this video?" -- um, create a `FileInputStream` using the `File`. "I also need name of this video?" -- um, call `getName()` on the `File`.

Comment: Let me check again. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What about getting video duration?

Comment: @mallaudin: I have no idea. You can't get that with an arbitrary `content` `Uri` either.